# Test cases for a weather widget

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, testcase, test-creation

In one of my recent interviews, there was a question:

> Write the functional and non-functional test cases for a weather app / widget. Note: Test coverage is important than numbers.

I wrote the below list of test cases. But I was given only 2 out of 5 marks. My questions are:

1. What are test cases that I'm missing?
2. I've not performed non-functional testing. What are the non-functional test cases for this application?
3. How do I improve on non-functional testing?

My answer to the interview question:

- Happy path: verify that weather forecast is correctly shown for the given city
- Temperature should be switchable between Fahrenheit and Celsius.
- User should be able to choose multiple cities
- All the settings and configurations should be correctly stored and read
- Correct images should be shown for each weather type. (e.g: thunderstorm, sunny, rain)
- Forecast is broken down to time slices (e.g: 12 PM, 1 PM, 2 PM and so on)
- Temperature graph is correct and smooth
- Forecast should be shown for N number of future date (e.g: for the next 1 week)
- All the images should be bundled with the application
- When there is a network failure and unable to reach server, appropriate message should be shown
- There should not be unnecessary error messages shown
- Widget layout should automatically resize based on user selection / screen resolution

Answer (score 1):

Types of non functional testing are:

- Performance Testing
- Load Testing
- Failover Testing
- Security Testing
- Compatibility Testing
- Usability Testing
- Stress Testing
- Maintainability Testing
- Scalability Testing
- Volume Testing
- Security Testing
- Disaster Recovery Testing
- Compliance Testing
- Usability Testing
- Portability Testing
- Efficiency Testing
- Reliability Testing
- Baseline Testing
- Endurance Testing
- Documentation Testing
- Recovery Testing
- Internationalization Testing
- Localization Testing

So, you can perform the Load testing, for example, - how many people can use this app?

Some of your answers are non-functional test cases by the way:

- Temperature graph is correct and smooth (Usability testing)
- Widget layout should automatically resize based on user selection / screen resolution (Partability testing)
- > When there is a network failure and unable to reach server, appropriate message should be shown

To test reliability: Not only show the message, but when server will be available again application should show forecast automatically.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please recommend how I can improve myself in non functional testing? Do you have suggestions for books?

Answer (score 1):

You can use some of the below-mentioned test cases for your question that helps in validating the functional testing requirement in software testing services company.

1. Ensure weather widget ask to enable auto location if it was disabled.
2. Ensure weather forecast is correctly locate your place automatically if auto location is enabled
3. Ensure forecast should be available in hour by hour and day by day wise.
4. It should also shows the Precipitation, humidity and wind percentage apart from the temperature.
5. There should be search fields to find weather for other places.
6. Weather forecast should also display the minimum and maximum temperature of the day.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the scenarios like below can be considered

1. Checking the language representation - Multilingual
2. Multiple Location
3. Auto location
4. Enable Manual location selection
5. Checking the fonts and Themes